# why is this sql using temporary?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

my sql:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT UserId, id, count(UserId) Num
FROM m_periodmaterial
WHERE UserId IN (?) AND id IN (?)
GROUP BY UserId AND Id
ORDER BY NULL
```

explain result:
[image]

The explain result shows that `Group By` uses temporary table, but [mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html) said **The most important preconditions for using indexes for GROUP BY are that all GROUP BY columns reference attributes from the same index, and that the index stores its keys in order**.

I think `UserId` and `Id` are primary key(index) which satisfy the reqirement.

ps: I used ```ORDER BY NULL`` to avoid using filesort.

Comment: My english is poor. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `GROUP BY UserId AND Id` is strange - unless that's a mysql "feature", you probably mean `group by userid, id`

Comment: OH!! It really work! using temporary disppeared when I replaced AND with a comma.

Comment: Heh, to be able to group by a boolean like that.  As expected from MySql.  Most other RDBMS would throw a syntax error on that.